# Move image in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried a few examples on the internet, but those who tried failed. I carry an image at run time , it is running fine , but I can not move the image that is loaded into a picturebox ,

Follows the code :

```
public partial class imagem : Form { private CarregaDados parent = null; int width; int height;

    public imagem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       

    /// <summary>
    /// Cria uma referencia entre os form
    /// Assim conseguimos controlar os elementos do outro form
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_parent"></param>
    public imagem(CarregaDados _parent)
    {
      this.parent = _parent;
    }

    public void CarregaImagem(string caminho)
    {
        Image image =  Image.FromFile(caminho);            

        //valores da largura  e altura
        int width = image.Width;
        int height = image.Height;

        //verificar a largura
        //e o pixel em que deve comecar a imagem
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        imagemPictureBox.Image = image;
    }

    //Primeiro ponto na imagem carregada
    private Point firstPoint = new Point();
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;        

    private void imagemPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;        
    }

    private void imagemPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            imagemPictureBox.Left = (imagemPictureBox.Left + e.X) - x;
            imagemPictureBox.Top = (imagemPictureBox.Top + e.Y) - y;
        }
    }

    private void imagemPictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            imagemPictureBox.Left = x;
            imagemPictureBox.Top = y;
        }
    }



}
```

I put the picturebox within Panel . I am not able to move the image, someone could tell me what is wrong

Comment: Did you wire up those handlers for the PictureBox?  Select the PB then in the Properties Pane (bottom right of the screen) click on the "Lightning Bolt" Icon.  Scroll down and find the Events you are interested in: MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp.  Select each one and change the DropDown to the right so that they point to the correct method.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You try to move a picturebox inside a panel, is that right??

Comment: I have a picutebox I put a picture just want to move it horizontally @TaW

Comment: That means 'yes'? Have you __hooked up__ those three events? Also, if you want only horizontaly movement don't change the Top value!

Comment: yes, did the three events, but I am still unable to move the image . @TaW

Comment: Please try to be clearer in your responses! Now I still don't know if you actually __hooked up__ the event or merely have written their code? __Set a break point at the beginning of the mousedown.__ If it does'n't stop there they are not hooked up...

Answer (score 0):

**Add these to the designer**

```
this.imagemPictureBox.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.imagemPictureBox_MouseMove);

this.imagemPictureBox.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.imagemPictureBox_MouseUp);

this.imagemPictureBox.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.imagemPictureBox_MouseDown);
```